# AVAudioPlayer plays one data (one time) and then repeatedly plays another data (multiple times)

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I am developing an audio app which needs to play two data (ex: dataA and dataB). For the purpose of the app, it should play the audio data in this order:

| dataA | dataB | dataB | ...... repeat N times of data B ... |

An easy solution of it would be creating a super large NSData that contains the above data structures (1 dataA + N dataB). However, it is inefficient, especially when N > 10000.

In Android or other systems that I can directly control the audio play buffer, I can simply push dataA to the play buffer and then have a for loop to put dataB as many times as I want (without allocating a super-large buffer to save the repetition of dataB).

How can it be achieved by AVAudioPlayer? (NOTE: for the purpose of the app, I need the dataB being played directly after dataA with 0 delay. So it is impossible to use multiple AVAudioPlayer classes)

Answer (score 1):

create two AVPlayer instances, one for playing aData and one for playing bData.

```
let aDataPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: aData_URL)!)
let bDataPlayer : AVPlayer? = nil
var counterForbPlayer : Int = 100 //whatever your n value is
```

use `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` to get notified when a player finishes playing.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadNextudio), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)


func loadNextudio() {
        if self.bDataPlayer == nil {
              bDataPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: bData_URL)!)
              bDataPlayer.play()
              counterForbPlayer -= 1;
        }
        else {
              if counterForbPlayer > 0 {
                  bDataPlayer?.currentItem?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                  bDataPlayer?.play()
                  counterForbPlayer -= 1;
              }
        }
    }
```